# WWW::Mechanize - how to POST without affecting page stack and/or current HTML::Form object?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm using [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) to automate placing 'orders' in our supplier's portal (with permission). It's pretty straight-forward to do so by filling the relevant form fields and `submit`ing as normal.

However, the portal has been built with a JavaScript-capable client in mind, and some short-cuts were taken as a result; the most significant short-cut they took is that as you progress through a "wizard" (series of forms) with normal POSTS, they require that you "deallocate" some resources server side for the "previous wizard step" by doing an AJAX POST. In pseudo-code:

```
GET page #1
fill the fields of page #1
POST (submit the form) --> redirects to page #2.
POST (ajax request to "/delete.do") 
fill the fields of page #2
POST (submit the form) --> redirects to page #3.
POST (ajax request to "/delete.do")
fill the fields of page #3.
...
```

What's the easiest approach to do those `ajax request to "/delete.do"` requests?

I've tried...

**Appoach (A)**

If I inject a new form (referencing `/delete.do` in the `action`) into the DOM and use `submit` then the mech object will no longer have the `HTML::Form` object built from the previous `redirects to page #X` step.

If I just use `back()` from that point, does that make another `GET` to the server? (or is it just using the prior values from the page stack?)

**Approach (B)**

If I just use the `post()` method inherited from LWP::UserAgent to send the POST to `/delete.do` I get a security error --  I guess it's not using the cookie jar that has been set up by WWW::Mechanize.

Is there some canonical way to make an 'out-of-band' POST that:

- Does use/update WWW::Mechanize's cookie jar
- Does follow redirects
- Doesn't alter the page stack
- Doesn't alter the current HTML::Form object

---

**UDPATE:** 
For anyone trying to replicate the solution suggested by [gangabass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/347767/gangabass), you actually need to:

> **(1)** Subclass `WWW::Mechanize`, overriding `update_html` such that a
>   new content can be injected into the HTML on demand.
>
> This content would normally be parsed by `HTML::Form::parse()`. The
>   override sub needs to alter the first non-self parameter `$html`
>   before calling the original implementation and returning the result.
>
> ```
> package WWW::Mechanize::Debug;
> use base 'WWW::Mechanize';
>
> sub update_html {
>   my ($self,$html) = @_;
>
>   $html = $WWW::Mechanize::Debug::html_updater->($html)
>     if defined($WWW::Mechanize::Debug::html_updater);
>
>   return $self->SUPER::update_html($html);
> }
>
> 1;
> ```
>
> **(2)** In the main program, use `WWW::Mechanize::Debug` as per
>   `WWW::Mechanize`
>
> ```
> use WWW::Mechanize::Debug;
> my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Debug->new;
> ```
>
> **(3)** Inject the HTML form which will need to be `submit()`ed.
>
> ```
> { 
>   my $formHTML = qq| 
>     <form action="/delete.do" method="POST" name="myform">
>       <!-- some relevant hidden inputs go here in the real solution -->
>     </form>
>   |;
>
>   local $WWW::Mechanize::html_updater = sub {
>     my ($html) = @_;
>     $html =~ s|</body>|$formHTML</body>|;
>   };
>
>   # Load the page containing the normal wizard step content.
>   $mech->get($the_url); 
>
>   # This should how have an extra form injected into it.                            
> }
> ```
>
> **(4)** In a new scope `clone()` the mechanize object, fill the form and
>   submit it!
>
> ```
> { 
>    my $other = $mech->clone;
>    my $myform = $separate->form_name('my_form');
>    $myform->field('foo' => 'bar'); # fill in the relevant fields to be posted
>    $myform->submit;
> }
> ```
>
> **(5)** Continue using the original mechanize object as if that form
>   submission had never occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `clone` your Mech object and make POST from cloned version. Something like:

```
{
    my $mech = $mech->clone();
    $mech->post(....);
}
```

But of course it will be better to make sub for this.

Comment: Ah, and it uses the same cookie jar. Excellent.